# Javascript function call with/without parentheses

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, parentheses, function-calls

code_0:

(calling `foo` without parentheses)

```
function foo(){
    console.log('hello world');
}

setTimeout(foo, 2000);
```

This is how `code_0` was executed:

```
start -> wait for 2 seconds -> 'hello world' displayed -> end
```

code_1:

(calling `foo` with parentheses)

```
function foo(){
    console.log('hello world');
}

setTimeout(foo(), 2000);
```

And this is how `code_1` was executed:

```
start -> 'hello world' displayed immediately -> wait for 2 seconds -> end
```

Why would the program perform so differently when I called the function with parentheses? What is the underlying mechanism?

Sorry if this question is too trivial. But I could't find an explanation on any javascript tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setTimeout(foo, 2000)` passes the function `foo` and the number `2000` as arguments to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(foo(), 2000)` calls `foo` and passes its return value and the number `2000` to `setTimeout`.

In the first example, you’re not calling the function at all, just passing it as an argument like any other value.

As a simpler example, just log it:

```
function foo() {
    return 5;
}

console.log(foo);   // console.log is passed a function and prints [Function]

console.log(foo()); // foo() is called and returns 5; console.log is passed 5
                    // and prints 5
```

Comment: So what if the function foo has an argument. Like: 

function foo(arg){
console.log('hello' + arg);
}

How do I use setTimeout on foo but also pass the parameter 'world' to foo?

Comment: @Delsin: You can pass a function that calls that function in turn. For example: `setTimeout(function () { foo('some argument'); }, 2000);`. There is also a built-in function on functions, `bind`, that sets `this` and some leading arguments: `setTimeout(foo.bind(null, 'some argument'), 2000);`

Comment: @RyanO'Hara - Making that a little complex, aren't ya? After the delay argument any extra args you give get sent to the function. Example: `setTimeout(foo, 2000, myArg1, myArg2, myArg3);`Why not just do that?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara - Nevermind, just answered my own question by remembering that a bunch of IE versions don't support that. But to be fair, bind isn't much better supported by IE either.

Comment: @JimboJonny: I didn’t want to make the answer specific to one usage.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code snippet, the function `foo` is being **passed to the timeout**. That means that `foo` gets called after 2 seconds when the timeout expires.

In the second code snippet, the function `foo` is being **called to decide what to pass to the timeout**. So `foo` gets called before the timeout is set. Since `foo()` doesn't return anything, nothing happens when the timeout expires.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, `foo` is

```
function foo(){
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

whereas `foo()` is

`console.log(hello world)`

The **setTimeout()** method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds, and this function is supposed to be the first parameter to it, in your first case you are passing a function that is why the behaviour is expected and in the second case you are passing `console.log(...)` which is not a function, so it is executing `foo()` first and prints in console `hello world` then waits for 2 sec and do nothing and thus showing wierd behaviour.

**See**

`typeof foo; // is function`

`typeof foo(); // prints hello world in console first and then says undefined.`

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference between `foo`  and `foo()` is the following:

```
function foo() {
   alert("bar");
   return "baz";
}

console.log(foo); // gives "function"
console.log(foo());  // gives "baz"
```

`foo` is a reference to the function body itself while `foo()` *executes* the function. Thus

```
setTimeout(foo(), 2000);
```

passes the return value ("baz") to the function `setTimeout`(which will result in an error). `setTimeout` expects an "executable" function as first argument, so you need to pass in a reference to an existing function.

Answer (score 1):

> The point of confusion here is that you're not realizing that using
>   `foo` without parentheses is **not** calling the function...it's only referencing it.

`foo` is the reference to the function itself. To call a function (i.e. actually execute its code) you reference it with parentheses at the end (e.g. `foo()`). In a practical sense that means:

```
// references the function itself
// ...you could call one() now and it would run the function foo
var one = foo;

// runs/calls the function, and var two will then be whatever foo returns
var two = foo();
```

So in the first example you are NOT calling the function. You are passing the function `foo` to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` will then *call* it after a delay.

In the second example you *called* foo immediately and passed whatever `foo` returns to setTimeout (which setTimeout couldn't do anything with, because that return value likely wasn't another function). So your function was executed immediately and then nothing would have happened (except likely some errors) after `setTimeout` was done with its delay.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy solution. You can use parentheses and pass data to the function if needed.

`<script>
function foo(){alert("hello world")}
setTimeout(function() {foo()}, 2000)
</script>`