# What is the difference between methods being called inside ananynomous methods and methods directly assigned to properties

Tags: flutter

Could anyone please explain the difference between if I call the method doSomeAction in both the ways.

```
doSomeAction() {
        ...
}
 

   
  GestureDetector() {
    onTap: () {
      doSomeAction();
    }
  }

  GestureDetector() {
    onTap: doSomeAction;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that you have one additional indirection.

Here, when a tap happens, a function is called that does nothing but call your function:

```
onTap: () { doSomeAction(); }
```

While this version directly calls your function. Without the empty redirection in the middle:

```
onTap: doSomeAction;
```

You only really need the first version, if your method signatures do not match and you have to do something about it. If you already have a method that has the exact signature required, and you want to do nothing but call it directly, you can just pass it as in version #2. Version #1 in that case is just a lot of unnecessary extra characters.

Comment: What happens if I use onTap: doSomeAction()

Comment: You will most likely get a compile error. That's not valid. It would only be valid if your method returned another method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497620/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-the-function-without-parentheses-and-with. Could you please take a look at that link and look at (peter Haddad's) reply. He talks about executing immediately...  Could you please explain what he was trying to say

Comment: He is trying to say that "onTap" expects a function reference. The name of a function to call at a later point in time. The name of a function is given without (), because if you add the () if would actually call the function instead of pass it's reference along.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are similar in functionality.

But, the main difference is that if you wrap your action inside an anonymous function, you could have more than 1 action. For example:

```
  GestureDetector() {
    onTap: () {
      // Action 1
      // Action 2
      // Action 3 and so on
    }
  }
```

On the other hand, if you directly assigned it, it will allow you to do **one single action**.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `onTap: doSomeAction` you actually don't call it - you just say that `doSomeAction` function will be called when the button is pressed.