# Difference between Function and Function() in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a doubt where I'm passing a function as a parameter, for onPressed, like event, I would declare a field like `final void Function() onPressed`, There are some code where I have seen declarring fields like `Function someFunction`, I would like to know what is the differnce between using Function and Function(). Thanks,

Comment: check this out please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803614/difference-between-myfunction-myfunction-and-myfunction-call-in-dart-flutt

Answer (score 0):

The main() function came from Java-like languages so it's where all programs started, without it, you can't write any program on Flutter even without UI.

The runApp() function should return a widget that would be attached to the screen as a root of the widget Tree that will be rendered

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in doc, Function is:

```
part of dart.core;

/// The base class for all function types.
///
/// The run-time type of a function object is subtype of a function type,
/// and as such, a subtype of [Function].
```

Now, Function(), is literally a function, see the example:

Here you can use this:

```
final Function() func = () {};

ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: func;
)
```

But you can not:

```
final Function func = () {};

ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: func;
)
```

Here you get the following error:

```
The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

Otherwise, you can use:

```
Function func() {
    return () {};
}

ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: func;
)
```

Use `Function somename` when you need to return a function from a method.

Use `Function() somename` when you need to use this, literally, as a function.

Answer (score 0):

As per Flutter docs:
`Function` is the base class of all the function types. It means it represents all the functions.

Adding parenthesis like: Function() makes it one without any parameter.

To sum up: `Function` is general and `Function()` is more specific.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, lets take a look whats is braces actualy means.
The main difference between `Method();` and `Method`, is that in first case, you call a method instant and its all. If you'l try to do `var someStuff = Method()`, `someStuff` will get a returning value of `Method()`;
In second case, when you use `Method`, you actually do not call it, because its a link to a method. Because of it is a link, you cant pass an arguments (which places in braces), and if you try to make set variable like this: `var someStuff = Method;`, variable `someStuff` will contains a link to a original `Method()`, and you can call it in code, and it'l work same.
That means, when you pass a link to a `onPressed:`, and if link has right signature (in and out param), you haven't write whats goes in method and out, all what you should to do will looks like: `onPressed: Method`. Dart automatically understand, what params in and out, by comparing theirs signature.